# Laravel 5.1 Combine Form Request and Validator

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I'm using form requests class. Work fine:

```
class EventFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
   public function rules()
   {
      return [
            'event' => 'required|min:10|max:255',
            'event_description' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            'url' => 'url',
            'date' => 'required|date',
            'start_time' => 'required',
            'location.street' => 'required|max:255',
            'location.house_number' => 'required|min:1|max:5',
            'location.place' => 'required|max:255'
        ];
   }
}
```

*But now, I have to add complexer rules, such as combined with Validator. Below the new rules() method of my EventFormRequest class:*

```
public function rules()
{
    $v = \Validator::make($this->request->all(),
        [
            'event' => 'required|min:10|max:255',
            'event_description' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            'url' => 'url',
            'date' => 'required|date',
            'start_time' => 'required',
            'location.street' => 'required|max:255',
            'location.house_number' => 'required|min:1|max:5',
            'location.place' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);

    $v->sometimes('category_id', 'required|numeric', function($input) {
        return $input->event_type == 'known';
    });

    return ($v->fails() ? $v->messages() : []); // validator validates the rules, but returns the messages
}
```

You see, category_id is required if the event type is 'known'. In the form request rules() method, I cannot return the applied rules as array (see example 1) from the validator, but only the messages().

I'm inspired from here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class EventFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'event' => 'required|min:10|max:255',
            'event_description' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            'url' => 'url',
            'date' => 'required|date',
            'start_time' => 'required',
            'location.street' => 'required|max:255',
            'location.house_number' => 'required|min:1|max:5',
            'location.place' => 'required|max:255'
        ];

        if ($this->request->get('event_type') == 'known') {
            $rules['category_id'] = 'required|numeric';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```